# How can I ensure Socket Timeout errors from my app, rather than 403 errors from Nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, clojure, reverse-proxy, socket-timeout-exception

I wrote a search API using NodeJS / HapiJS. I set this to run on port 40000 and then I reverse-proxied it to port 80 via Nginx. Nginx does nothing on this machine except act as a reverse proxy to the many apps we have running on various ports.

My company uses the API to look up client data. It is highly configurable, but we don't know which configuration would give us the best results. So I wrote a massive regression test in Clojure. The app fires 10s of millions of requests at the API, testing the different parameters for the configuration.

Occasionally the API gets overwhelmed and so the Clojure code gets a SocketTimeoutException. That's fine. I wrote some code that catches all the SocketTimeoutException and waits a while and then retries the call.

All of the above is great and we love it.

However, once in awhile, instead of getting a SocketTimeoutException because of a slow response from the API, we instead get a 403 error from Nginx. This is not cool. I'm not even sure why it happens, though I assume Nginx sometimes gets tired of waiting for a response from the API, and then perhaps decides the app is offline? Though in that case I would expect a 500 error, not a 403. But possibly Nginx treats some reverse proxies as permission issues?

Anyway, slow responses and SocketTimeoutException are fine with us, but 403 errors from Nginx are not okay. How do I ensure that Nginx remains quiet, so my Clojure app can talk to my NodeJS app without interruption?

Comment: Have you checked your nginx error logs to see why its returning a 403?

Comment: I don't see anything relevant in the logs. I only see:

Comment: 2017/02/19 05:40:27 [warn] 23701#0: *122 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /usr/local/nginx/proxy_temp/5/00/0000000005 while reading upstream, client: 113.4.17.16, server: localhost, request: "POST /animals/v3/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:40002/", host: "dev04.zzz.com"